# getArguments() inside fragment always null

Tags: android

I try to view tablayout with dynamic inside activity, data from server.

Data from server is retrieved successfully.

Inside Activity:

onCreate:

```java
setupTab();
loadBarang();
```

setupTab:

```java
private void setupTab(){
        adapterViewPagerBarangOrder = new AdapterViewPagerBarangOrder(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPagerBarangOrder);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
```

request to server

```java
private void loadBarang(){
...
// success
adapterViewPagerBarangOrder.setGroupBarangs(listGroupBarang);
...
}
```

AdapterViewPager:

```java
public class AdapterViewPagerBarangOrder extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    List<CreateOrderFragment> fragments;
    List<GroupBarang> groupBarangs;

    public AdapterViewPagerBarangOrder(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
        this.fragments = new ArrayList<>();
        this.groupBarangs = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void setGroupBarangs(List<GroupBarang> groupBarangs) {
        this.groupBarangs = groupBarangs;
        for (GroupBarang groupBarang: groupBarangs) {
            fragments.add(CreateOrderFragment.newInstance(groupBarang.getListBarang()));
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.size()>0? fragments.get(position) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return groupBarangs.size()>0? groupBarangs.get(position).getGroupName() : null;
    }
}
```

Fragment

```java
public class CreateOrderFragment extends BaseFragment {
    private static final String ARG_LIST_BARANG = "create_order_arg_list_barang";
    private AdapterBarangOrder adapterBarangOrder;
    private List<Barang> listBarang;
    private EmptyRecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private CartManager cartManager;

    public CreateOrderFragment() {
        listBarang = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            listBarang = (List<Barang>) getArguments().getSerializable("ARG_LIST_BARANG");
        }
// HERE CHECK listBarang ALWAYS NULL
// ANY HELP?

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_order, container, false);
        cartManager = new CartManager(getContext());

        adapterBarangOrder = new AdapterBarangOrder(getContext());
        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.create_order_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterBarangOrder);
        adapterBarangOrder.setListBarang(listBarang);
        return view;
    }

    public static CreateOrderFragment newInstance(List<Barang> listBarang){
        CreateOrderFragment fragment = new CreateOrderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ARG_LIST_BARANG, (Serializable) listBarang);

// HERE CHECK listBarang NOT NULL and NOT EMPTY

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

}
```

Check size of listBarang inside fragment.newInstance not null and was not empty

but check inside fragment.oncreate arguments always null

Comment: All the fragments getting null?

Comment: as comment in fragment.oncreate

// HERE CHECK listBarang ALWAYS NULL
// ANY HELP?

the fragments not null, getArguments() not null to, but when getArguments().getSerialize(....) inside onCreate of fragment always null;

Comment: Your model is Serializable, right?

Comment: yes it was double check, implemets Serializable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
listBarang = (List<Barang>) getArguments().getSerializable("ARG_LIST_BARANG");
```

with

```
listBarang = (List<Barang>) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_LIST_BARANG);
```

Key should be same when setting and getting arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You're using

```
getSerializable("ARG_LIST_BARANG")
```

But putting in the Serializable by using

```
putSerializable(ARG_LIST_BARANG, (Serializable) listBarang);
```

Where the value of `ARG_LIST_BARANG` is `"create_order_arg_list_barang"` - you're not using the same key on both sides. You should remove the quotes in `getSerializable` to actually use your variable:

```
listBarang = (List<Barang>) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_LIST_BARANG);
```